# Having trouble with event handling and DOM appending with form in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, forms, fetch, render

I'm creating a simple flashcard app using vanilla JS, CSS, HTML. 
Being a JS noob, I'm getting my butt kicked with DOM manipulation when trying to do basic CRUD (I fetching to a Rails API for persistence).

I'm running around in circles using console.log and debugger trying to understand the flow of my app. These problems arise w/o refreshing the browser. On create, 3 extra 'fantom' card will appear. Also having trouble with edit where it also creates a new card. I'm also trying to maintain an `allFlashcard` array. The confusion for me is a) how to use one function to render new or updated card and b) how to use the same form for create and edit.

The Code -

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" />

    <title>CrashCard</title>
  </head>

    <body>
      <!-- header -->
      <header>
        <h1>Crash Card</h1>
        <button id="modal-btn" class="button">Create Card</button>
      </header>

      <!-- modal -->
      <div id="my-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>


            <!-- form  -->
            <form class="ui form" id="form">
              <div class="field">
                <label>Card Front</label>
                <input type="text" name="card-front" placeholder="Card Front" id="card-front" value="">
            </div>
              <div class="field">
                <label>Card Back</label>
                <input type="text" name="card-back" placeholder="Card Back" id="card-back" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="field">
              </div>
              <button class="ui button" id="submit" type="submit">Create</button>
              </form>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- card -->
      <div id="card-container">
      </div>



      <script type="text/javascript" src="src/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 200px;
height: 260px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 3px;
perspective: 800px;
display: inline-flex;
}

:root {
  --modal-duration: 1s;
  --modal-color: #b4bdc5;
}


/* body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
} */

.button {
  background: #428bca;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #3876ac;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 60%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  animation-name: modalopen;
  animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
}

.modal-header h2,
.modal-footer h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-header {
  background: var(--modal-color);
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.modal-footer {
  background: var(--modal-color);
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


header {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
text-align: center; 
}





/* .sticky {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 background-color: white;
 display: block;
 z-index: 1;
} */

/* .parallax { */
 /* The image used */
 /* background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556745750-68295fefafc5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80 */
/* https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556745750-68295fefafc5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80 */
/* 

/* Set a specific height */
 /* min-height: 300px; */
 /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
 /* background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:auto; */
/* } */

#card-container {
  margin-top: 2em; 
  padding: 5%; 
 height: 100vh;
 overflow-y: scoll;
}

.card {
justify-items: center; 
padding: 2px; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
transition: transform 1s;
color: white;
position: relative;
}

.card h2 {

text-align: center; 
margin: 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.card h4 {
text-align: center; 
position: relative;
margin: 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
overflow-y: scroll ;
}

.card .front {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1; 
}

.card .back {
background: rgb(241, 241, 248);
transform: rotateY( 180deg);
color: black;
text-align: center; 
z-index: 2;
display: 
}

.card.flipped {
transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log("DOM is loaded");



    // set variables and DOM elements 

    let allFlashcards = [];
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const card = document.querySelector('#card-container');
    const modal = document.querySelector('#my-modal');
    const modalBtn = document.querySelector('#modal-btn');
    const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');


    // fetch all cards


    fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(flashcards => {
                allFlashcards = flashcards
                renderCards()
     });



    // render cards to DOM

    const renderCards = () => {
        console.log("in rendercard")
        return allFlashcards.map(c => {
            return card.innerHTML += `
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card" data-card=${c.id}>
                    <i class="black delete icon" id="delete-card"></i>
                    <i class="black edit icon" id="edit-card"></i>
                    <h2 class="front" data-id=${c.id}>${c.body_front}</h>
                    <h4 class="back">${c.body_back}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
           `
        })
    };

    // listen for card click and flip

    card.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.dataset.id) {
            return e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
        } else if (Array.from(e.target.classList).includes('back')) {
            return e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
        }
    });

    // ****** MODAL SETUP ********

    // Modal Events

    modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
    window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

    // Open
    function openModal() {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        createCard()
    }

    // Close
    function closeModal() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Close If Outside Click
    function outsideClick(e) {
        if (e.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    // create new card
    const createCard = () => { 
        console.log("in create")
         form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger 
            console.log("I was cliked too")
            const cardFront = document.getElementById('card-front').value
            const cardBack = document.getElementById('card-back').value
            fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards', {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    body_front: cardFront,
                    body_back: cardBack
                })
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(newCard => {
                    allFlashcards.push(newCard)
                    closeModal()
                })
         });
    };



    // delete cards

    card.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const clickedCard = e.target.parentElement
        const foundCard = allFlashcards.find(fcard => {
            return fcard.id == clickedCard.dataset.card
        })
        console.log(foundCard)
        if (e.target.id == "delete-card") {
            console.log(card.parentElement)
            card.lastElementChild.remove(clickedCard)
            confirm("Do you want to delete this card?")
            fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards/${foundCard.id}`, {
                method: "DELETE"
            })
                originalCardIndex = allFlashcards.indexOf(foundCard)
                allFlashcards.splice(originalCardIndex, 1)
                console.log("in Delete:", allFlashcards)
        };
    });


    // edit cards 
    card.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.id == "edit-card") {
            openModal()
            editCard()
        }
     });

    const editCard = () => {
        console.log("in editcard")
        const cardFront = card.querySelector('.front').innerText
        const cardBack = card.querySelector('.back').innerText 
        const clickedCard = e.target.parentElement
        const foundCard = allFlashcards.find(fcard => {
            return fcard.id == clickedCard.dataset.card
        })
            document.getElementById('card-front').value = cardFront
            document.getElementById('card-back').value = cardBack
            let submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')
            submitBtn.innerText = "Edit"
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => { 
             e.preventDefault()
            const editedCardFront = document.getElementById('card-front').value
            const editedCardBack = document.getElementById('card-back').value
            fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/v1/flashcards/${foundCard.id}`, {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    body_front: editedCardFront,
                    body_back: editedCardBack
                })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(editedCard => {
                originalCardIndex = allFlashcards.indexOf(foundCard)
                allFlashcards.splice(originalCardIndex, 1, editedCard)
                console.log("in Edit:", allFlashcards)
            });
        });
    };




}); // end DOMContentLoaded
```

Overall I'd love some advice on how to configure this properly.

Comment: Why so many returns?  `allFlashcards.forEach(c => {
            card.innerHTML += ` instead of `return allFlashcards.map(c => {
            return card.innerHTML += `

Comment: Also: `card.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.dataset.id) {
            return e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
        } else if (Array.from(e.target.classList).includes('back')) {
            return e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
        }
    });` can be written `card.addEventListener('click', e => 
           e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('flipped')
    );` since you are toggling regardless

Comment: You should reduce that code to a [mcve]. We don't, for example, need to see all that HTML/CSS unless it's absolutely required for the question.